# Adding a density plot to a pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I was able to replicate the example in http://www.pgfplots.org/tikz/examples/graph-in-table/. Now, I'd like to ask two concrete questions:

1. How can I add a vertical space between rows that applies to the plots as well?
2. Is there a way to plot a normal density on top of each interval?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change `\arraystretch`. To synchronize the plot, you need to redefine `y` to become `y=-\arraystretch\baselineskip`. I also added some Gaussian curves centered around the means and with the widths being controlled by the errors.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.txt}
name z p mean lci uci
Afear -0.96  0.33 -0.42 -1.28 0.44
Anofear 0.09 0.93 0.04 -0.85 0.94
B+2 0.29 0.78 0.10 -0.59 0.79
B+1   0.84  0.40  0.30 -0.40 1.00 
B1:1   2.19  0.03  0.80 0.08 1.52 
B-1   1.02  0.31  0.37 -0.33 1.07 
B-2   -0.10  0.92  -0.03 -0.72 0.65 
C+2   -1.11  0.27  -0.30 -0.83 0.23 
C+1   1.15   0.25  0.32 -0.22 0.86 
C1:1   -1.34  0.18  -0.38 -0.93 0.17 
C-1   0.43  0.67  0.12 -0.42 0.66 
C-2   -0.37  0.71  -0.10 -0.63 0.43 
D+2   0.41  0.68  0.12 -0.44 0.67 
D+1   -0.69  0.49  -0.20 -0.77 0.37 
D1:1   -1.33  0.18  -0.39 -0.97 0.19 
D-1   -1.21  0.23  -0.35 -0.92 0.22 
D-2   0.32  0.75  0.09 -0.46 0.65 
\end{filecontents}
%%%>
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{comment}
:Title: Graph within a table
:Tags: 2D;PGFPlotstable;Styles
:Author: Jake
:Slug: graph-in-table

We would like to plot a graph within a table column, similar to
http://texample.net/tikz/examples/weather-stations-data/ .

We will use the booktabs package for good table design,
and the multirow package.

The data is read using PGFPlotstable and the plot is typeset dynamically.

This code was written by Jake on TeX.SE.
\end{comment}

% Read data file, create new column ``upper CI boundary - mean''
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\data
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/error/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{uci}-\thisrow{mean}
    }
  }
}


% Define the command for the plot
\newcommand{\errplot}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[y=-\arraystretch\baselineskip,% <- added \arraystretch
        scale only axis,
        width             = 6.5cm,
        enlarge y limits  = {abs=0.01},%<-
        axis y line*      = middle,
        y axis line style = dashed,
        ytick             = \empty,
        axis x line*      = bottom
      ]
      % ``mean'' must be present in the datafile,
      %``error'' is the newly generated column
      \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
        table [x=mean,y expr=\coordindex,x error=error]{\data};
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\irow in {0,...,\the\numexpr\numberofrows-1}
      {\pgfplotstablegetelem{\irow}{error}\of\data
      \let\myerror\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\irow}{mean}\of\data
      \let\mymean\pgfplotsretval        
      \addplot[forget plot,domain=-1.5:1.5] 
      {0.5+\irow-exp(-(x-\mymean)*(x-\mymean)/(2*\myerror*\myerror))};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
% Get number of rows in datafile
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\let\numberofrows=\pgfplotsretval

% Print the table
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={name,error,z,p,mean,ci},
  % Booktabs rules
  every head row/.style = {before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style = {after row=[3ex]\bottomrule},
  % Set header name
  columns/name/.style = {string type, column name=Name},
  % Use the ``error'' column to call the \errplot command in a multirow cell
  % in the first row, keep empty for all other rows
  columns/error/.style = {
    column name = {},
    assign cell content/.code = {% use \multirow for Z column:
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
    {\multirow{\numberofrows}{6.5cm}{\errplot}}%
    \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
    \fi
    }
  },
  % Format numbers and titles
  columns/mean/.style = {column name = Mean, fixed ,fixed zerofill, dec sep align},
  columns/z/.style    = {column name = $z$, fixed, fixed zerofill, dec sep align},
  columns/p/.style    = {column name = $p$, fixed, fixed zerofill, dec sep align},
  columns/ci/.style   = {string type, column name = 95\% CI},
  % Create the ``(x to y)'' format, use \pgfmathprintnumber with `showpos`
  % to make things align nicely
  create on use/ci/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={\edef\value{(
      \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos,fixed,fixed zerofill]{\thisrow{lci}}
      to \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos,fixed,fixed zerofill]{\thisrow{uci}})}
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\value
    }
  }
]{\data}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so very much! The \arraystretch worked just fine. The second item refers to possibly plotting a normal bell curve on top of the interval.

Comment: @user3487128 Yes, that's what one could have guessed. Yet presumably you do not want a random bell curve, but one that represents the data. Then one could wonder if you want one per line (probably not) or a big one. There are not too many details in this item, and I'd also say that this may be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As each interval corresponds to a distribution, I'd like to plot a normal density per line.

Comment: @user3487128 Well, it is easy to add some Gaussian curves. Whether this is pretty is up to others to judge.